# Moose read-only Attribute Traits and how to set them?

Tags: perl, moose

How do I set a Moose read only attribute trait?

```
package AttrTrait;
use Moose::Role;
has 'ext' => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'ro' );

package Class;
has 'foo' => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'ro', traits => [qw/AttrTrait/] );

package main;
my $c = Class->new( foo => 'ok' );
$c->meta->get_attribute('foo')->ext('die') # ro attr trait
```

What is the purpose of Read Only attribute traits if you can't set it in the constructor or in runtime? Is there something I'm missing in [Moose::Meta::Attribute](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm)? Is there a way to set it using `meta`?

```
$c->meta->get_attr('ext')->set_value('foo') # doesn't work either (attribute trait provided not class provided method)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set it in the constructor:

```
package Class;
has 'foo' => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'ro', ext => 'whatever', traits => ['AttrTrait'] );
```

You just need to pass it to the right constructor (the constructor for the attribute).

Answer (score -1):

I use `default` to deal with `ro` attributes:

```
package Foo;
use Moose;
has 'myattr' => (is => 'ro', default => 'my value goes here');
```

And since you won't be setting `myattr`'s value anywhere else, the default is used.